# Passing a subset of a macro's arguments to another macro in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, nasm, preprocessor

I've been experimenting with macros in NASM recently, and despite reading the documentation, I still don't know if there is a way to pass a subset of a macro's arguments to another macro; and if there is, how to do it.

I'm aware I can do something like this

```
%macro A 1-*
    %rep %0
        db        %1
        %rotate   1
    %endrep
%endmacro

%macro B 5
    A %1 %3 %5
%endmacro
```

but I wonder if some equivalent of this is possible

```
%macro B 1-*
    A %1 %3 %5 ... %n ; Assuming n is odd
%endmacro
```

If iterating over odd indices is too complex, what about passing *all* arguments to another macro?

Thank you for your help in advance.

This question is not really about a bug or an error, but I've read chapter 4 (and skimmed through chapter 5) of NASM's documentation, as well as tried to experiment on my own hoping to come up with a solution, but nothing has brought any results. I didn't find anything on StackOverflow either, but I admit I didn't spend much time on this part.

Comment: You can use _"Macro Parameters Range"_ such as `%{1:-1}` to pass all arguments. It does not support a step value so you can't select the odd ones.

Comment: *This question is not really about a bug or an error* - That's a good thing, those are usually the least interesting and lowest future-value.  Checking the docs and then asking is fine for something non-obvious.

Comment: You can make a loop with `%rep` and append to a list like `%xdefine %%LIST %%LIST, %1` then `%rotate 2`. Wrap the `%1` in curly braces `{...}` if the parameters can contain commas. Then pass `A %%LIST`. The very first list entry may need special handling however. (If I pass things to `db` or `dw` eventually I often start out the list like `%define %%LIST ""` which these directives process as "empty string".)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I experimented with your suggestions a bit, and I managed to create a macro building a double-layer jump table as an exercise :)